# How to link library from github with no CDN to splunker or jsFiddler

Tags: github, package, cdn, jsfiddle, plunker

I am trying to create an simplified version of my problem at jsFiddler or plunker (so ill be able to ask a clearer question here).

My problem is that I am using a package (videojs-youtube) that is not on a CDN and I need to make it available.

I have tried to follow couple of answers that advise to use raw || raw2 || rawgithub  or any version of that - but that does not work.

Thanks

Comment: I've voted to migrate this to meta. Note that posting questions with links to code, as opposed to creating an SSCE, is discouraged.

Comment: SSCE? none of the acronomes I found makes sense. 
http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SSCE

Comment: small self-contained example.

Answer (score 0):

For code hosted in github you can use services like [GitCDN.xyz](https://gitcdn.xyz/)

For example: https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/eXon/videojs-youtube/master/src/youtube.js
This serves the files with the correct content type, compression and through a CDN.

Or you can use: https://min.gitcdn.xyz/repo/eXon/videojs-youtube/master/src/youtube.js
This one does the same as above, but with minification applied to html, css, and javascript files.

Full disclosure: I'm the project maintainer for GitCDN; and in the interest of fairness I will also mention that there is another service like ours: [RawGit.com](https://rawgit.com)